# How to rebind a package inside a Stored Procedure (DB2)

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I have a few Stored Procedures for my application (DB2 V 9.7.3). I need to rebind the packages corresponding to the Stored Procedures. I wish to get having them recompiled inside a Stored Procedure by retrieving the package names via a Cursor and rebind the packages one by one.

The command to do is

```
REBIND PACKAGE <schema>.<pkgName>
```

To execute this command, I tried the following options but both of them failed.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE <stmt>;

CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD(<stmt>);
```

Is there a way to get this accomplished? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to rebind the packages via the following routine

```
db2 "CALL SYSPROC.REBIND_ROUTINE_PACKAGE('P', 'SCHEMA1.PROC1', 'ANY')"
```

- P -> stands for Stored Procedure
- SCHEMA1.PROC1 -> stored procedure name with the schema
- ANY -> an optional input argument supported for backward
  compatability. You can use ANY or CONSERVATIVE.

  Please refer these links for more information.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21250633

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0009863.html

**Note:** Explicitly rebinding the associated package does not revalidate the routine. Revalidate an invalid routine by using automatic revalidation or explicitly by using the ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS procedure. Routine revalidation automatically rebinds the dependent package.